# MySQL - union 1 SELECT table with 1 SUM/COUNT table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. One has a record in column `Column` named `Overall Experience` and another table has an actual COLUMN named `Overall Experience` filled with survey scores.

Now, this means that I do not have a union in the traditional sense where 2 tables share the same record value, but rather I am trying to link 2 tables by selecting the `column name` from table 1 and then `count` data from that specific column in table 2.

Here the query I am struggling with. How does one go about this?

EDIT:

I plan on running a `mysqli_fetch_array` and then `echo` the variable in a table where I need them. Something like this:

```
$sql = "
(SELECT `Column`, `Department`, `Target` FROM `table_1` WHERE `Column` = 'Overall Experience')
UNION
(SUM(`Overall Experience` >= 8) / COUNT(*) * 100 AS med_osat,
COUNT(`Overall Experience`) AS med_osat_cnt FROM `table_2`)";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $med_osat = $row['med_osat'];
    $med_osat_cnt = $row['med_osat_cnt'];
    $med_osat_tgt = $row['Target'];
    $med_osat_dept = $row['Department'];
    $med_osat_name = $row['Column'];
    $med_osat_var = ($med_osat_tgt - $med_osat);

    // echo variable in a table
}
```

Thank you

EDIT 2:

To clarify the table structure:

**Table 1**

ID, Column, Department, Target

**Table 2**

100+ columns of survey data, of which one column name matched the `Column` value in table 1

Comment: How is your expected result look like?

Comment: @tcadidot0 please see the edit.

Comment: Does the first part of the query (from `table_1`) return more than one row?

Comment: @Nick, no, the result is exactly one row with details such as the `Target` score for the `Overall Experience` score of the survey.

Comment: The `UNION` won't work that way.. besides, you're missing a `SELECT`

Comment: @Armitage2k , I edited your question and add an expected output.. please check if it's how you would expect.. If not, you can edit or just remove it then replace with your version. Thanks

Comment: @tcadidot0 Thank you, but the posted `CROSS JOIN` throws a syntax error?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the downvote. Just to understand, I posted a table structure, sample query and preferred output, all of which is not enough for you to recreate the situation?

Comment: As above. But whatever floats your boat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `CROSS JOIN` the two sets of values together since each query only returns one row:

```
$sql = "
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM (SELECT `Column`, `Department`, `Target`
      FROM `table_1`
      WHERE `Column` = 'Overall Experience') t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(`Overall Experience` >= 8) / COUNT(*) * 100 AS med_osat,
                   COUNT(`Overall Experience`) AS med_osat_cnt 
            FROM `table_2`) t2";
```

This will yield an output suitable for the processing you show in your PHP code.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f27fc9e6f03d465a545d9484b72bd621)

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score -2):

First of all the number of columns and the name of the columns should be the same while you are applying the **UNION**.

The second thing it would be better if you will also share the table structure so I can have a look at the structure of both table, The More suggestion would only be available question is properly understandable.

YOU CAN TRY OVER HERE :

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4a7c5/1